# Cannot initialise class within ActionListener... please help!

Tags: java, swing

I have a Breadth-First algorithm that scans a graph of nodes.

I am new to UI and Swing. I want the algorithm to run when the OK button is pushed etc. using the text box strings as parameters.

The program will not work becuase it cannot initialise my class.

This code works perfectly in console. I just don't understand UI.

I should add that start.getText() and end.getText() are text boxes where the user enters the start and end stations.

```
    JButton okButton = new JButton("Get Route...");

    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            final BreadthFirstShortestPath init = new BreadthFirstShortestPath("/Users/wakemana/Documents/GC02 Java/Tube Stations List/station_names.txt"
                    , "/Users/wakemana/Documents/GC02 Java/Tube Stations List/tube_edges.txt");

            init.breadthFirst(start.getText(), end.getText());

            ArrayList<String> path = init.getPath();

            for (String station : path) {

                System.out.println(station);

            }

        }
    });
    buttonPane.add(okButton);
```

And for anyone that can help, here is the stack trace:

```
/Users/wakemana/Documents/GC02 Java/Tube Stations List/station_names.txt
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:222)
    at alex.graph.breadthfirst.StationGraph.<init>(StationGraph.java:19)
    at alex.graph.breadthfirst.BreadthFirstShortestPath.<init>(BreadthFirstShortestPath.java:22)
    at alex.graph.breadthfirst.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:103)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6352)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6117)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4714)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:635)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: Have updated... please note: is is definitely not the file name(s).

Comment: Don't say that it's definitely not the file name, since as yet, you don't know what the cause of the problem is.  Have you placed debugging code in the BreadthFirstShortestPath class yet?  Are you assuming that the user.dir is one thing but it in fact is something else?  This isn't being called from a jar file is it?

Comment: And how big is BreadthFirstShortestPath?  It would be nice to see where the NPE is being thrown in that class -- what line causes it to occur.  If you could show more code, it would probably help us.

Comment: Yes apologies... Was a rushed question from frustration. All fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is NOT with the `ActionListener`. Your object `BreadthFirstShortestPath` is not being constructed properly. This is the relevant part of the stacktrace:

```
/Users/wakemana/Documents/GC02 Java/Tube Stations List/station_names.txt
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:222)
    at alex.graph.breadthfirst.StationGraph.<init>(StationGraph.java:19)
    at alex.graph.breadthfirst.BreadthFirstShortestPath.<init>(BreadthFirstShortestPath.java:22)
    at alex.graph.breadthfirst.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:103)
```

I think you are wrong and that the path is not being found. Your command line variables could differ from an IDE environment.

Comment: Yeah I can see that. There is nothing wrong with the files. Like I say it all works perfectly in command prompt.

Comment: Never been this frustrated before... I HATE UIs! Will have to deal with them one day

Comment: @AlexW No problem. For Java UI help, I'd recommend installing Netbeans and seeing the code that the GUI builder creates. Also check out http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: @brian: I have found all your posts and answers in this thread to be exceptional except for the one above. I find code from NetBeans' Matisse code generator to not be very helpful in showing good Swing coding techniques, especially with regards to use of layout managers and help in understanding what is going on behind the scenes.  But, we are all entitled to our opinions. :)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels True that generated Netbeans code is bloated and sometimes strange. However, I mostly meant that it is good sandbox to play around in when starting UI development. You can create a JFrame File Type automatically, add a button, attach an event, change some properties and then check out the code to see how you would programatically accomplish the same result. This I found easier than wading through a bunch of APIs. As my knowledge grew, I depended less on the generator and more on looking at the APIs. But yes, what works for one person might not for another. : )

Comment: I think I'll stick to HTML as my interface model of choice.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex W : Try using : **System.getProperty("user.dir")** to get the current directory of the context , then use **" ../ "** to get the **relative path** for the location.I think that your using **absolute path** here is causing nullpointer exception as it could not find that location.